# Custom session handler - how to use it correctly?

Tags: php, security, session

I've gotten some odd results when testing this and I can't seem to figure out exactly how to use it.  I've got this custom session handler:

```
require_once('database.php');

Class linusLogin_Session {

        private $_database;
        private $_key = '*withheld*';

        public function __construct() {
            $this->_database = new linusLogin_Database;
            session_set_save_handler(
                array($this, "_open"),
                array($this, "_close"),
                array($this, "_read"),
                array($this, "_write"),
                array($this, "_destroy"),
                array($this, "_gc")
                );
            session_name('llSSID');
            session_start();
            }

        public function _open(){
            return TRUE;
            }

        public function _close(){
            return $this->_database->close();
            }

        public function _read($id){
            $data = null;
            $result = $this->_database->selectSessData($id);
            if ($result !== FALSE) {
                $result = $this->_decrypt($result);
                return $result;
                }
            else
                return "";
            }

        public function _write($id, $data){
            $access = time();
            $data = $this->_encrypt($data);
            $result = $this->_database->replaceSessData($id, $access, $data);
            }

        public function _destroy($id){
            return $this->_database->destroySessData($id);
            }

        public function _gc($max){
            $old = time() - $max;
            return $this->_database->gCollectSessData($old);
            }

        private function _encrypt($data) {
                *encryption withheld*
                return $data;
            }

        private function _decrypt($data) {
                *decryption withheld*
                return $data;
            }

        public function setKey($key) {
                $this->_key = $key;
                }
        }
    $session = new linusLogin_Session;
```

So, am I correct here in having the file instantiate it's own class (last line)?  Or does the class instantiate when I use `session_start()`?  I have `session_start()` in the construct, I'd prefer that be the only place it exists across all the documents -- is that a good practice?  I've had trouble with this handler before caused by not using `session_start()` on a page even though it's in the handler.  (I truly hate those notices that say

> `session_start()` already called, ignoring `session_start()`

As a side question -- I keep hearing I should regenerate the `session id` every request -- but what does request mean?  Does that mean every http request or does that mean every change in the session?  What's the best practice for regenerating id's (without using the "*every request*" line).

Also, any suggestions on security would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom session handlers are used by PHP's session code. It's an object to be acted on, not the actor. Thus, you should just define the custom methods, and then session start elsewhere.

For example:

```
// Make sure you make changes like this one:
Class linusLogin_Session implements SessionHandlerInterface {

// This doesn't need to do anything with session config or call any session_* functions
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_database = new linusLogin_Database;
    }
}
```

And then...

```
include "mysessionhandler.php";
$session = new linusLogin_Session();
session_set_save_handler($session);
session_name('llSSID');
session_start();
// The rest of your site goes here
```